# Sending form using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to send a form using jQuery and it's not working. This code with a `<a>` tag works fine, but inside a form using the submit button doesn't.

```
$('#send-comment').click(function(){
    var id_parent = $('#id_parent').val();
    var comment_text = $('#comment-box').val();
    var user_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['log_id']; ?>;
    var new_id = <?php echo $id_new; ?>;
    $.post( "dn-functions.php", { func: "registerComment", id_parent: id_parent, comment_text: comment_text, user_id: user_id, new_id: new_id })
    .done(function( data ) {
    alert( data );
    });
});
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"This code with a tag works fine, but inside a form using the submit button doesn't."* - `$form="show it";`

Comment: You might be better off using a plugin like http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Use a form submit event instead of a click event and use `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('#send-comment').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_parent = $('#id_parent').val();
    var comment_text = $('#comment-box').val();
    var user_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['log_id']; ?>;
    var new_id = <?php echo $id_new; ?>;
    $.post( "dn-functions.php", { func: "registerComment", id_parent: id_parent, comment_text: comment_text, user_id: user_id, new_id: new_id })
    .done(function( data ) {
    alert( data );
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure you are submitting the form and your request is not being sent since you're leaving the page on form submit.
So pass the event and prevent the default action of form submit.

Comment: THANK YOU below9k!!! It worked!! If you don't mind, would you please explain what preventDefault do? I'd like to understand what was the problem.... :)

Comment: The default action to clicking a submit button is to submit the form that it is wrapped in. So instead of submitting the form traditionally you prevent that and use your jquery method instead. This could be done with anchors (<a>) too. Instead of going to that link (href) you could prevent that and do something else completely different. I can't find a list of default actions for elements, sorry. If someone can found one, I would like to see it also.